# how to access a members of an abstract super class from nested members of another child class

Tags: nested, abstract, super, members

my problem is to access a members of an abstract super class from nested members (class or struct) of another derived class

for example:

```
    public abstract class DataAccessLayer {
        public DataAccessLayer(string _connectionString) { //some code }

        //some member functions
    }
```

another classes will be derived from this class

```
    public class DataStructureLayer : DataAccessLayer {
         pubic DataStructureLayer(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { // NOP }

         //Here we have structures or classes
         //we want to access members of a superclass "DataAccessLayer"
         //from these struts
         public struct Books { 
               //members
         }
    {
    }
```

i want to use the super class members inside the nested structs of the derived one without making an instance from this, is there a way?

Comment: What technologies are you using?

Comment: what do you mean >> if i know your idea - .net technology

Comment: And what language? Is it C#?

Comment: In your code DataAccessLayer is not specified as the base class of DataStructureLayer. Read more about inheritance in C# here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: of course .. i forgot it and i edited it now, but the main problem is to use the members of the super into nested members in child one >> it is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the DataAccessLayer and the DataStructureLayer. The constructor of DataStructureLayer calls the constructor of DataAccessLayer. So the single problem you still have is that you cannot call the constructor from Books? In that case you can do this:

```
DataStructureLayer dtl = new DataStructureLayer("yourconnectionstring");
```